# Type in the textbox with LETTERS only and also with only one Minus sign(-) only Preferably using the ASCII code

Tags: c#, winforms, ascii

I want to use the ***ASCII code*** of ***minus sign***. Is there possible way on doing it? Use minus sign ***only once***.
***45*** is the ASCII code of minus sign(-)

```
private void txtcity_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back);// e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.45);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow using the hyphen/minus character only once, you need to check if the TextBox already contains one. If it does, you set `e.Handled` to true. The rest of your logic should work fine.

You may use something like this:

```
private void txtcity_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // If you want to use the ASCII code, for some reason.
    const int minusAsciiCode = 45;

    // if (e.KeyChar == '-')
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)minusAsciiCode)
    {
        e.Handled = txtcity.Text.Contains("-");
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back);
    }
}
```